# AWS Lambda Custom Parameters

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am getting started with a serverless application and you define functions as this:

`exports.handler = async function(event, context) {` from what I've seen and I have not been able to find any examples where the parameters are different.

I was wondering if there was any point in the flow where I could use event to parse as MyRequestObject and then define my method as:

`exports.handler = async function(MyRequestObject) {`

I'm trying to use openAPI and go with a contract based API that is clearly defined and create SDKs from the code so I'm looking to make it pretty specific if possible.

I know that I can do inside the function the following:

`const MyObject: MyObject = JSON.parse(event.body) as MyObject;`

but I'm looking to have one method that maybe uses reflection to then pass the correct object depending on what the function is expecting.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to wrap lambda handler function to your function.

```
interface MyRequestObject {
  name: string;
}

const customHandler = (func: (params: MyRequestObject) => Promise<any>) => {
  return async (event, context) => {
    const body = JSON.parse(event.body) as MyRequestObject;
    return await func(body);
  }
}

exports.handler = customHandler(async (params: MyRequestObject) => {
  // do something with param
  // return the result
});
```

`customHandler` will return a function, this is lambda handler function.

Inside of the function, it tries to convert `event.body` to `MyRequestObject` and executes `func` (your function), then returns result of `func` as result of lambda function.

**Update**: Generic version, `customHander` accepts any type as `params`

```
const customHandler = <T extends {}>(func: (params: T) => Promise<any>) => {
  return async (event, context) => {
    const body = JSON.parse(event.body) as T;
    return await func(body);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hoangdv, this is helpful but I was wondering if there's a way to have a generic customHandler that can handle any of my functions.

Say I have these two methods:

getListOfObjects(MyRequestFilter):
createOneObject(MyCreateRequestObject):

Where i'd want `const body = JSON.parse(event.body) as MyRequestObject;` to instead of being one object, to be either MyCreateRequestObject or MyRequestFilter depending on what function is passed to the customHandler

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the help.